# The electric flux of a sphere within a cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, gauss-law

I am assigned this problem in my Physics course, and I just can't seem to wrap my head around how this should be solved. We had a similar problem where we had to find the electric flux of a sphere within a sphere which I was able to understand since the electric field would just be perpendicular to the outer sphere. However, I don't understand how should I take this problem. Any help or even a reference would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

A uniformly charged insulating sphere with radius $r$ and charge $+Q$ lies at the center of a thin-walled  hollow  cylinder  with  radius  $R  >  r$  and  length  $L  >  2r$.  The  cylinder  is  non-conducting and carries no net charge.

(a)  Determine  the  outward  electric  flux through  the  rounded  “side”  of  the  cylinder, excluding the circular end caps.

(b) Determine the electric flux upward through the circular cap at the top of the cylinder.

(c)  Determine  the  electric  flux  downward  through  the  circular  cap  at  the  bottom  of  the cylinder.

(d) Add the results from parts (a)–(c) to determine the outward electric flux through the closed cylinder.

(e) Show that your result is consistent with Gauss’s law.

Comment: I am not sure what you didn't understand, you might want to add what exactly you didn't understand in this question. Use the definition of electric flux and find the solutions.

Comment: Do you know vector calculus?